# Watir :- After long execution , watir is not able to fill a text filled?

Tags: ruby, watir

I have written a long script, but after executing many lines of code there is a text field is to be filled, but it is not filling that text field, on browser it can be seen that it is getting yellow but value not getting filed, i have tried many methods but no result

```
result = ff.text_field(:name, "scode").exist?
if result
ff.text_field(:name, "scode").set(Wipro)
end
```

this is one method i tried

Comment: Please post relevant HTML or link to the page, if it is public.

Comment: I got the answer myself. Now i fill it by ff.text_field(:name, "scode").value = "James"

Answer (score 2):

Is that your actual code?  If it's not are you using a variable / method to set the text that gets entered into the text_field.set ?

Make sure it's not trying to input a blank string.

(sure wish I could post comments, as this is a shot in the dark, rather than a guaranteed solution).

Comment: you need to develop a little reputation before it will let you enter comments.  I'll give your answer a little bump since it's moving in the right direction, and that should help a little with your reputation score.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to type "Wipro" then you will need a quotation mark around it.
So this should work too:

```
ff.text_field(:name, "scode").set("James")
```